# Can I skip generating the {proxy+} when creating Rest API using Amplify

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am currently playing around with creating rest-api:s with amplify. I am trying to create the following structure:

- /helloText
- /helloText/{name}

But I get the following error when trying to push the backend:

```
Unable to create resource at path '/helloText/{proxy+}': A sibling ({name}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed
```

As I understand, it is because Amplify is creating "greedy paths" by default.

When manually removing these "greedy paths" from the template file RestTest-cloudformation-template.json it works.

Is it somehow possible to create these paths by using only the command line?

Answer (score 4):

There is no configuration switch for that in amplify-cli. You need to create an override. Reference: [Amplify override api](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/restapi/override/).
Run:

```
amplify override api
```

Then edit generated **override.ts** like:

```
import { AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate) {
  const {paths} = resources.restApi.body;
  Object.keys(paths).forEach((path) => {
    if (path.includes('{proxy+}')) {
      delete paths[path];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: OMG! I'm having a similar issue. If this works, I will hate amplify even more. Why tf?

Comment: It works, I am using it in my own project. Unfortunately, Amplify CLI is limited, so we are forced to mutate the configuration JSONs like that.

Comment: It worked for me (unfortunately, as well), thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked for me. And maybe the "override" strategy will open up more possibilities. So far I've yet to fall in love with Amplify :-D